# xpath - limit search to node not working?

Tags: javascript, xpath, greasemonkey

What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to limit my xpath search to a specific row in my table but my query always returns the content of the span in the first row:

```
var query = "//span[contains(@id, 'timer')]";
var root = document.getElementById('movements').rows[1];
document.evaluate(query, root, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.textContent
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> "//span[contains(@id, 'timer')]"
> ```

**The problem**: This is an *absolute* XPath expression and it ignores the fact that you are evaluating it from a specific row.

**Solution**: To achieve the wanted result use:

`.//span[contains(@id, 'timer')]`

Comment: How did you know, that I was looking for YOUR solution since a couple of hours googeling around... a simple period saved my day. I was wondering why I cannot limit the searching range from ´document´ or ´document.body´ to ´this[0]´ , which represents a chosen DOM element. UP++ for your period, which I did not found explained anywhere else :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the first row:

```
var root = document.getElementById('movements').rows[1];
```

This will get the second row:

```
var root = document.getElementById('movements').rows[2];
```

You need to specify the correct index of the row you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var query = "//td//span[contains(@id, 'timer')]";
```